# Empty tag is replaced with unicode replacement character

Tags: component, joomla-2.5, tinymce

I'm saving rich texts from my custom component. It uses wysiwyg editor. Therefore there are html codes also.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<!-- More here -->
<tr>
<td colspan="5"> </td>
</tr>
<!-- More here -->    
</tbody>
</table>
```

After saving and viewing them again I can see 'replacement character-U+FFFD' in empty td tag. I tried to add nbsp html entity. But it is replaced with empty character.

I want to save this td tag empty. Is there any way around to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Which editor you use? If Tiny Editor go in Plugins -> Editors -> Tiny Editor and change the Entity Encoding setting to raw, or try all 3 options and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: And also: are you copying/pasting your code in the editor field ? Try again by only typing your code directly.

Comment: Why are you inserting whitespace in the empty `<td>` anyway? If it is empty, leave it empty, don't insert a space.

Comment: I'm using Tiny editor. Encoding is raw

Comment: Please see Farahmand's answer.It works for me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your admin side, go to "Extensions" -> "Plug-in Manager". Then click on "Editor - TinyMCE".

Now enter the `td[*]` for "Extended Valid Elements" and save it.

[image: Joomla TinyMCE empty tags]

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped.